# Blender Made an object inside my object

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender and I am trying to make a character player. I just finished creating the model and somehow messed everything up. There is a character object inside my character object. But, they are the same object. It is almost as if blender copied every vertex and re-added it slightly out of line. Looking for some help and advice. Attached is a drive link to my blender file.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QALbFkmGPriKuchhaha0Xx1PFYW3G2-x

Comment: in edit mode do "Remove Doubles"

Comment: Thank so much for the help! But, that didn't work. It kind of seems like the vertices are not exactly doubles of each other. It's like there is a slightly smaller person inside my bigger person. :/

Comment: If it is not too much trouble. I would really appreciate it if someone could take a look at the blender file in my original post. Explaining what happened in words doesn't seem to do the situation justice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I dunno how you got into this situation, but @cegaton is right, "Remove Doubles" will help.  In this case I had to bump up the Merge Distance to .06 to remove what looks like all of the doubles, although it's hard to be certain.  And then I had to recalculate the normals.